# Moving wet appliances away from sink around kitchen L bend and past oven

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, washing-machine, drainage, dishwasher

I am renovating my kitchen so that I can introduce a dishwasher and extend my counter top. My kitchen is a small L shaped one, and in order to get everything I want in the design I need to move my wet appliances (washing machine and dishwasher) across to the other side of the kitchen, around the L corner and to across to the other side of the oven from the sink.

The distance from the sink to the new appliances, measured along the wall, will be about 420cm for the furthest appliance.

I have spoken to a handful of tradesmen and kitchen designers and I have been getting mixed responses about whether this will work from a plumbing perspective. Some have suggested that it will be fine and others have suggested that there will be drainage issues with the appliances.

So I wanted to get the opinions of the experts here before committing to this new design.

Here is a picture of the current kitchen with the positions of the new we appliances annotated. Other things to note about the picture; there will be a small thin cabinet introduced to the left of the oven so the dishwasher will not be immediately next to it, and the fridge is moving entirely out of view.

[image]

If you could let me know if you think that this design will work out that would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Why do the contractors you've spoken with believe there will be drainage issues, and why are you unsure about what they are telling you? They have a strong incentive to do what you ask: it's what they get paid for. If some of them are apprehensive, and unless they are trying to sell you a different solution that is even *more* complicated (ie. expensive), what else could be motivating their response besides "doing the right thing" ?

Put another way, the ones that are willing to do whatever you ask might just be willing to move your sink into the ceiling and install your toilet on the back patio, as long as they get paid for it. The ones that are apprehensive get nothing out of it by telling you to not proceed, besides maintaining their professional integrity.

I would weight heavily the advice from the professionals that are willing to forgo a quick buck to maintain their reputation.